# Is there any way in c# to have Type which includes itself?

Tags: c#, generics

One way to code what I want is the following, but I don't really like the new hiding

```
public class Bar
{
    public TReturn Baz<TReturn>()
      where TReturn : Bar
    {
        return this as TReturn;
    }
}

public class Foo : Bar
{
    public new TReturn Baz<TReturn>()
      where TReturn : Foo
    {
        return base.Baz<TReturn>() as TReturn;
    }
}

class Test
{
    public void Main()
    {
      var foo = new Foo();
      var foo2 = foo.Baz<Foo>();
      Assert.IsInstanceOfType(foo.GetType(), foo2);
    }
}
```

Instead I want to know if a generic Type can include itself? Something like the following.

```
public class Bar<TReturn>
    where TReturn : Bar<TReturn>
{
    public TReturn Baz()
    {
        return this as TReturn;
    }
}

public class Foo<TReturn> : 
    Bar<TReturn>
    where TReturn : Bar<TReturn>
{
}

class Test
{
    public void Main()
    {
      var foo = new Foo<???>();
      var foo2 = foo.Baz();
      Assert.IsInstanceOfType(foo.GetType(), foo2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at this:
[Article by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx)
He explains this pattern in some depth, it is a variant of the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Dog Ears for the name of the pattern and an initial hint.

For reference my current solution was to clean up Foo so it did not need the type passing in.

```
public class Bar<TReturn>
    where TReturn : Bar<TReturn>
{
    public TReturn Baz()
    {
        return this as TReturn;
    }
}

public class Foo : Bar<Foo>
{
}

class Test 
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var foo2 = foo.Baz();
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(foo.GetType(), foo2);
    }
}
```